# Multiple jquery ajax requests same callback

Tags: jquery

I have a list of URLs to which I want to make requests.  The processing of the response is the same except for updating different parts of a page based on the url to which I made the request so I want to use the same callback for each request.

My problem is that the callback gets called for the first request, and then again for the second request before processing of the first request finishes.  That is somewhat expected, but I would have thought that it would go back and pick up processing the first request when finished with the second.  This happens even with async set to false - apparently the synchronous part stops when the callback is called.

The only solution I've found is to issue the second request in the callback.  Is there a better way?

Here's the problem code:

```
function doStuff() {
   // populate a var urls array with data from user input
   var urls = new Array();
   // ... code to populate urls ...

   // loop through urls and send requests
   for (var i = 0; i < urls.length; i++) {
       $.ajax({url: urls[i],
               success: handleResponse,
               dataType:'html'});
   }
}

function handleResponse(data) {   
    url = this.url;
    // process based on url
}
```

Answer (score 0):

[jQuery Deferred](http://api.jquery.com/category/deferred-object/)  is useful in your case

Comment: Perhaps, but that seems more useful if I know the number of urls ahead of time.  In my case I don't (I've edited the sample code to reflect this).  Maybe I can still make use of Deferred - not sure yet.